# Trying to calculate factorial but I am having a type error [python]

Tags: python, factorial

I am trying to write a program asking users to input a positive integer and calculate factorial.

This is what I did

```
def main():
    getN()
    fact()
    print (n,"! is ",num)

def fact():
    num=1
    while n>=1:
        num=num*n
        n=n-1
    return num

def getN():
    n=input("Enter a positive integer: ")
    if not n%1==0:
        print("Enter a positive integer: ")
    return n

main()
```

But when I run this code, I got the error saying type error: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

I have to get a postivie integer and want to use getN function to guarantee that it is a positive.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What part of the code does the error refer to?

Comment: 1) See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for how to get validated user input. 2) Variables defined in a function aren't visible outside the function. As Donkey Kong mentions, you should be passing `num` to `fact`, and you need to save the values returned by your functions into variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error message, it's always a good idea to post the whole error message including the stack trace. Your question should be self explaining without code if possible. So provide the error message but also analyze the error message yourself.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):  
   File "/home/labbi/git/sandkasten/sandkasten.py", line 21, in <module>
     main()   
   File "/home/labbi/git/sandkasten/sandkasten.py", line 2, in main
     n1 = getN()
   File "/home/labbi/git/sandkasten/sandkasten.py", line 17, in getN
     if not n%1==0: 
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The error message says the TypeError occurred on line 17 which is the operation in your if statement. The only string can be contained in the variable `n`.

Your problem is that `input()` on line 16 returns a string so you can't use it for numeric operations. You can convert strings with `int()` as bellow.

When you have fixed it you will also notice a few mistakes in your main function. You're calling `fact()` and `getN()`. Both return values but you don't store them even though you're trying to use the returned values.

```
def main():
    n_result = getN()
    num_result = fact(n_result)
    print (n_result,"! is ",num_result)


def fact(n):
    num=1
    while n>=1:
        num=num*n
        n=n-1
    return num


def getN():
    n = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
    if not n%1==0:
        print("Enter a positive integer: ")
    return n

main()
```

Furthermore for readability reasons I would also like to point you to the [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especially to the [chapter about whitespace](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a tricky error message, but `if not n%1 == 0:` is an attempt to perform mod division, however `n` is still a string. You need to cast the input to `int` with

```
n=int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
```

Your code still won't work however, because you are referencing variables everywhere before their assignment, and in functions for which they are not defined. I would consider re-arranging the order of your functions, and ensuring that all relevant parameters necessary for each function are passed - currently you don't use function parameters at all.

As an aside, you got that error message because `%` is also used in string formatting operations to mark the start of a conversion specifier. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

## Use this code

def factorial():
    i = int(input())

```
mul = list(range(1, int(i)))

for eve in mul:
    i = i * eve

return i
```

print(factorial())